# Разрешение экрана в условии PHP

Tags: php

Хочу через php создать условие, чтоб в зависимости от разрешения экрана показывался разный контент. Можно ли как-то взять код из css: @media only screen and (max-width:480px) и прописать его в условие php, чтоб при разрешении до 480px выводился один контент, а если разрешение будет больше 480px, то показывать другой контент? Не знаю как именно "@media only screen and (max-width:480px)" внедрить в php

Comment: В контексте php у пользователя нет никакого экрана. Переносите эту логику на клиент.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18890053/4822490

Answer (score 1):

Не надо это в php делать. Если контент разный, то решите это банально через css, скрывая ненужные блоки.

Два разных контента в два разных блока. Показываются в разных разрешениях. Вот и все

Comment: Я так раньше и делал, но в самом коде остается же контент, его не видят люди, но видят поисковики. Мне нужно чтоб лишнего ничего не отображалось в коде. Это не выход считаю. И мне уже подсказали другие ребята, что с помощью PHP это не делается, но можно сделать на JS

Comment: Если не хранить контент ни в каком виде в коде на фронтенде, то можно сделать через ajax. При смене разрешения отправляешь запрос, и получаешь нужные данные, и через js вставляешь в код.

Answer (score 0):

При первом переходе на страничку ставишь куки на яваскрипте с разрешением и обновляешь страничку.

Со стороны php можно опираться на эту куки. Но лучше подумай о user agent

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev передать разрешение через куки в пхп - не ответ?